# Horrible case statement for displaying a title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

This thing kills me:

```
     def report_subtitle
        case params[:kind]
          when 'position'   then  h("for Position: #{@current_company.positions.find_by_id(params[:id])}")
          when 'grade'      then  h("for Grade: #{params[:id]}")
          when 'location'   then  h("for Location: #{Location.find_by_id(params[:id])}")
          when 'department' then  h("for Deparment: #{@current_company.departments.find_by_id(params[:id])}")
          when 'supervisor' then  h("Employees who report to #{@employees.first.supervisor.full_name}")
          when 'eeoc'       then  h("for EEOC Code: #{params[:id]}")
    end
```

Comment: What does your view template look like? If the report subtitle has this many cases, I'd expect that this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with this method:

- The parameter `kind` is not descriptive enough. Is this a kind of report? Is it `report_type`?
- You seem to be looking up a `Location`, `Position` and `Department` using the same id. I'm not sure this is possible, but if it is, you should rather use the relations rather than id-lookups.
- This method is trying to generate a report's subtitle, presumably in the controller. The conditional of the `case` statements should be replaced by polymorphism. Something like separate classes which all respond to the same method.

I don't quite understand the context of your code, but aim for something like

```
class PositionReport
  # ...
  def subtitle
  end
end

class GradeReport
  # ...
  def subtitle
  end
end
```

Then you are reasoning about different report types, each of which handles it's own subtitles (and other logic).

Just my two cents.